# Existence of solution to "weird" integral equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-equations

in my current work I come across an integral of the form
\begin{align}
x(a) = \int_{\Omega} f(a, u) x(u) du
\end{align}
where $\Omega$ is $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, e.g. $\Omega = (0,1)$. The functions $f$ and $x$ are differentiable and integrable on $\Omega$. I am interested in conditions for the existence of a solution $x(t)$ to the above integral. My problem is that the integral does not fit into the usual form on integral equations, i.e. something along the lines of
\begin{align}
x(a) = \int_{-\infty}^a f(k, u) x(u) du.
\end{align}
Do you know of any works regarding the existence of a solution to the first integral equation? A formula for explicit solutions would of course also be nice. Thank you!

Comment: This is a Fredholm equation of the second kind. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation

Comment: $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}$ or $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ or $\Omega \in \mathcal B(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley Thank you! I will look into this

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the comment, it it $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. I corrected it.